# videocapture on hololens 2 with vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, vuforia, hololens

I am working on an application running on Hololens 2. It is built with Unity 2022.3, MRTK3 (v3.0.0) and Vuforia Engine 10.17.4.

I am using model targets and they work very well.

However, the user should be able to record a short video (including user voice comments) at the end of the work with the app, while still in the app.

I am using UnityEngine.Windows.WebCam and the VideoCapture class.
Unfortunately, it seems like Vuforia Behaviour has exclusive access to the camera.
I am following guidelines at: https://library.vuforia.com/getting-started/vuforia-engine-api-unity
No VideoCapture instance and no mp4 video is created even if I pause Vuforia before trying to create the VideoCapture instance (if I create a separate project without using vuforia but keeping the rest "as is", the video is recorded).

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Answer (score 1):

Pausing is not enough, you have to completely deinitialize Vuforia Engine.

A possible alternative is to use the Vuforia Engine Session Recorder feature https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/recording-and-playback

The Session Recorder should work on Hololens and produces an mp4 file that can be played back anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I followed both. For unknown reasons, VideoCapture still does not record video even with vuforia deinitialized (I ask and wait for vuforia to pause, then I register a callback for deinitialization and call the VuforiaApplication.Instance.deinit and in the deinitialization  callback I call VideoCapture.CreateAsync by passing a third callback, which is never called...).
The second way (SessionRecorder) works better but I am investigating why it does not include audio (Unity player capabilities for microphone granted). Still a good step forward.

Comment: As described here https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/session-recorder-api-overview to get audio working you have to add to Project Settings -> Player -> Publishing Settings -> Capabilities the following: VideoCapture (when capturing audio).

Comment: It looks like I finally solved this issue.
It turns out that (for unknown reasons), the Unity app was not asking me for microphone access permission, even if it was included in the requested Publishing Settings -> Capabilities. It started to behave correctly only after I removed from Publishing Settings -> Capabilities other two capabilities (which I was requesting without really using).
After finally being asked about the mic and granting its usage, the videoplayer solution started working.